# Trying to run an IOS emulator on Ubuntu for Vue Native

Tags: ios, vue-native

I am trying to jump into vue native and develop an ios compatible app. I installed expo and went through the install guides etc but I run npm start and I get the QR code, I try to choose the `i` option and get this error:

```
Opening on iOS...
(node:1257057) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn osascript ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:1257057) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 13)
```

I am guessing it is because I need xcode to run an ios simulator...is there no way around this? Do I have to go out and buy a mac just to develop for IOS even though I am using something like vue native or react native?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, access to a Mac is required to release an app for iOS; Regardless of what you use to develop the app, the Xcode toolchain is required to sign the binary to submit to the App Store and to build and sign binaries for testing on the simulator or real device.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the answer! I dont want to drop the cash on a mac lol. I guess android development it is.